# What is the purpose of desc in Fluentd?

Tags: ruby, fluentd

I'm writing a fluentd plugin and came across `desc`. From the [docs](https://docs.fluentd.org/plugin-development/api-plugin-base#.desc-description) I see that it means describe.

```rb
desc 'Postgres username'
config_param :user, :string

desc 'Postgres password'
config_param :password, :string, :secret => true
```

Take a look at the example above. I'm curious if `desc` is ever used by Fluentd Engine? Because when I run fluentd from a config file I don't see `desc` being used anywhere, at-least from the output I see. What is the purpose of this? Why not use comments instead?

Another example of desc being used is shown [here](https://github.com/Azure/fluentd-plugin-mdsd/blob/master/src/fluent-plugin-mdsd/lib/fluent/plugin/out_mdsd.rb).

Answer (score 0):

`desc` is a parameter typical in ruby [DSLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) as is commonly found in `rake` or `Rspec` for example.  You're writing a plugin which I assume is to be used in conjunction with [fluentd](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd). A [simple search yields results](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/search?l=HTML%2BERB&q=desc) such as `.erb` files which render string/text data.  This is one example of where such parameters could be used.

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826890/what-is-the-magic-behind-desc-description-on-rake) may also provide more insight.